# Exporting database to .CSV using SQL

Tags: mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin, admin

I am working on a project that requires an admin to be able to export a table from a database to .csv format. However when I try to run the query below in myphpadmin as a test i receive the following message with a big green check mark:

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 sec)

The table has over 60 records. The query i used is below:

```
 SELECT * FROM `User`
 INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\np\Desktop\test.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Also the file is not created in the location specified.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

   ```
   INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\np\Desktop\test.csv'
   ```

   to

   ```
   INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\np\\Desktop\\test.csv'
                   ^^     ^^  ^^       ^^
   ```
2. Make sure that account under which mysql process is running has enough permissions to write to a destination directory
3. Make sure that you don't already have a file with the same in the target directory. MySql won't replace the file. It only creates file afresh.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just have one quick question with regards to the permissions. I have checked them and these are the following permissions that are currently unchecked, I checked the FILE permission but still receive the same message;                      GRANT
SUPER PROCESS
RELOAD
SHUTDOWN
SHOW DATABASES
LOCK TABLES
REFERENCES
REPLICATION CLIENT
REPLICATION SLAVE
CREATE USER                                                       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
SHOW VIEW                                                        CREATE ROUTINE
ALTER ROUTINE
EXECUTE
CREATE VIEW
EVENT TRIGGER

Comment: Sorry for a long delay with the reply. In my answer I referred to the filesystem permissions in the destination directory. But you also need to have `FILE` MySQL permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the phpMyAdmin export functionality? Look for the Export tab from with a database or table. There's also a link from any results page (for instance, if you create a custom SQL query).